# How to insert a particular record 10 times in postgresql

Tags: cakephp-2.0, postgresql-9.3

I have 2 tables. Student master table and student qualification table. I want to select a record from the master table and insert it into the qualification table. The only problem is that in the qualification table, each student should have 10 records each.

For Ex: If student master has 5 records, student qualification table must have **5*10 = 50 records**

I have tried using Insert into qualification with select from master but the records are not saved for 10 times.

Below is my query:

```
    Insert INTO student.qualification(std_id,qualf,count)
    Select std_id,qualf,$i from student.master where status = 'pass');
```

$i because i am trying to repeat the loop 10 times

can anyone please suggest an alternative to achieve this result

Expected output:

```
    Master Table

Student ID
    1
    2
    3

Qualification Table
Student ID Qualification Count
1          A              1
1          B              2
1          C              3
......
1          J              10
2          A              1
...
2          J              10
```

Similarly other student records. As mentioned above, i am trying to use a for loop and within that loop the insert_ select query to increment the records
can anyone please suggest an alternative to achieve this result

Comment: You'll need to show some actual code instead of just SQL queries. Assuming that `$i` is a PHP variable, we'd need to see the PHP code that you're using, for example.